# How to use AUCTeX to create a PNG file of a TikZ picture using the 'standalone' package (macOS)?

Tags: emacs, auctex, macos

I would like to use AUCTeX to create a PNG image of a TikZ picture using [the `standalone` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone?lang=en). I use macOS Sierra.

According to the `standalone` documentation v1.2-2015/07/15 (section 4.6 *Conversion to images*, p. 15)

> Using the `convert` class option the standalone file can be easily converted to an raster image. This is done by executing an external program to convert the output file (PDF or PS) to an image (recommended is the lossless PNG format, but also others are supported).

According to subsection 4.6.1 *Conversion settings* (p. 15)

> Conversion settings can be given as the value of the `convert={<settings>}` option. By default conversion is disabled `(convert=false)`. If enabled without providing own settings (`convert,convert=true`) the following default settings are used: PNG format, a density of 300dpi, no explicit size and the output file name is given by `\jobname`, i.e. the name of the LaTeX document. Using the `convert` option with any value other than `false` will enabled it.

According to section 4.6.2 *Conversion software* (p. 16)

> The conversion requires an external image converter program to be installed. By default the two following tools are supported and either of them must be installed in order to use the conversion feature.  In order for an external program to be executed the `-shell-escape` option must be used for the compiler executable, e.g. `pdflatex -shell-escape filename`. Without this option no conversion is possible.
>
> By default the conversion program of [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is used for PDF LaTeX files [...]

So I used [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (a popular package manager for macOS) to install Image Magick. It was installed in the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.6-0`. I then added the following lines to my Emacs init file (`~/.emacs`) so that Emacs would know where to look for the Image Magick executables:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.6-0/bin/"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.6-0/bin/")))
```

After restarting Emacs, I wrote the following LaTeX manuscript, called `my_tikz_drawing.tex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,1)
   [rounded corners] -- (2,0) -- (3,1)
   [sharp corners] -- (3,0) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: default
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
%%% End:
```

and compiled it using `C-c C-a`.

The result was a PDF file, but the PNG file was not created, at least not in the same directory where the LaTeX manuscript was.

I then opened Terminal (the macOS command-line console), `cd`-ed to the directory containing the LaTeX manuscript, and executed the following command:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape my_tikz_drawing
```

The result was a `my_tikz_drawing.png` file in the same directory.

---

**A possible clue**

Executing the following command, which is found in the log file, once from the Terminal and once from Emacs (using M-!):

```
convert -density 300 my_tikz_drawing.pdf -quality 90 my_tikz_drawing.png
```

yields the following results.

- From the Terminal: The command executes silently and creates the file `my_tikz_drawing.png`.
- From Emacs: No PNG file is created, and an error message shows in the mini-buffer:

> convert: no images defined 'my_tikz_drawing.png' @error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254.

This is the same error that appears in the output from the Emacs pdflatex run.

Comment: What is AUCTeX set to execute when compiling?  The default may well omit `-shell-escape` option

Comment: @DaiBowen: This is why I used the `TeX-command-extra-options` file variable in the bottom of the manuscript. [According to the AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Processor-Options.html) this should have done the trick.

Comment: Exactly which version of AUCTEX are you using? I use an older one, 11.87 and there does not seem to be any options like that in the auctex `.el` files. Thus when I try your code, my Emacs just ignores the option

Comment: you need 11.88 for that and also to allow local variables (which are disabled by default)

Comment: @daleif: 11.90.2

Comment: what does the log file look like, that should show if latex was called with shell-escape and if so whether it found the convert program

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've found the following line 75% down the file: `runsystem(pdflatex  -shell-escape  -jobname 'test23' '\expandafter\def\csname s
a@internal@run\endcsname{1}\input{test23}')...executed.` And a couple lines later: `runsystem(convert -density 300 test23.pdf  -quality 90 test23.png)...executed.`. (OK, so I lied that the manuscript's name was `my_tikz_drawing.tex`; it's actually `test23.tex`...)

Comment: Just hit `C-c C-l` in Emacs (C might not be Ctrl on the Mac). That opens the log. The exact command executed is listed at the start of the log. Where exactly did you get the `runsystem` part from?

Comment: @daleif: `C-c C-l` doesn't open the log file, but rather the output buffer associated with the pdflatex run. It says: `Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful!
(standalone)              There might be something wrong with your
(standalone)              conversation software or the file permissions!

 ) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test23.log.` The log file doesn't start with the command executed, but with the following: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.5.23)  5 JUL 2017 17:09
entering extended mode`

Comment: Correct, it is the output log, but it still lists the latex call at the top in my 11.87: `Running `LaTeX' on `imf' with ``pdflatex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" imf.tex''`

Comment: @daleif: Oh, I see. The output buffer starts with: `Running 'LaTeX' on 'test23' with ''pdflatex  -file-line-error -shell-escape  -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" test23.tex''`.

Comment: Hard to debug from a distance, just take that log, and the log you get from a working run on the terminal and compare line by line in emacs with ediff or compare-windows or whatever, see where it goes wrong.

Comment: That seems to mention that you are using `-shell-escape`, did the rest of the output still say that it is being executed without?

Comment: @daleif: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. What exactly should I look for in the output buffer?

Comment: @daleif: There are two "log" files: the output and the .log file. The most significant place that the Emacs output differs than the terminal output happens in the very end of the Emacs output, where it says (just after `Output written on test23.pdf`): `(./test23.aux)convert: no images defined 'test23.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254. system returned with code 256 Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful!
(standalone)              There might be something wrong with your
(standalone)              conversation software or the file permissions!

 ) )`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Please see my previous comment, which was intended for you, but accidentally addressed to @daleif. As for the .log files, they are very similar, but there is one interesting difference: the Emacs log contains the line `(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/t/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty` where the Terminal log contains the  line `(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/t/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty`.

Comment: @daleif: Here's an experiment I've conducted. Perhaps it can point the way? I executed the command (which I found in the log file) `convert -density 300 test23.pdf  -quality 90 test23.png` from the Terminal as well as from Emacs (using `M-!`). When run from the Terminal, the command executed silently and produced the file `test23.png`. However, when executed from Emacs, it resulted in the error message: `convert: no images defined 'test23.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254.` and no PNG file was created.

Comment: Do you have many of these files? Then I'd jsut use `latexmk -shell-escape -pdf *.tex` to compile and convert all of them

Comment: @daleif: This is not an ideal solution for me. I'd rather generate the PNG files as I go along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs can't find the GhostScript executable. Run

```
which gs
```

in Terminal, and copy the path, say `/usr/local/bin`. Then add the following lines in your Emacs init file (say, `~/.emacs`), and restart Emacs.

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin/"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin/")))
```

(The first of these lines may not strictly be necessary, but it doesn't hurt...)

---

This answer was made possible thanks to the good people in the Image Magick Users forum, who answered [my post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=32267).